# Proving continuity of a map from $D^2$ onto $S^2.$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, universal-property

I am following the lecture note in topology given by our instructor. There I found a proof of the fact that $D^2/S^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^2.$ The proof of this result goes along the following lines $:$

> Let us denote the inverse of the stereographic projection from $S^2 - N$ onto $\Bbb R^2$ by $\mathscr I.$ Then define a function $f : D^2 \longrightarrow S^2$ as follows $:$
>
> $$ 
> f : x \longmapsto 
>   \begin{cases} 
>       \mathscr {I} \left (\frac {x} {1 - |x|} \right ) & x \in D^2 \setminus S^1 \\
>       N & x \in S^1 
>       \end{cases}
> $$
>
> This map is continuous and surjective and hence by universal property of quotient topology we have a bijective continuous map $\overline {f} : D^2/S^1 \longrightarrow S^2.$ Now since $D^2/S^1$ is compact (being the image of the compact space $D^2$ under the quotient map) and $S^2$ is Hausdorff it follows that $\overline {f}$ is a homeomorphism and this proves the result.

Here I don't understand why $f$ is continuous. It is clear that $f$ is a continuous bijection from $D^2 \setminus S^1$ onto $S^2 - N.$ But how do I show that $f$ is continuous  $S^1\ $? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $N$, please?  Oh wait, the north pole?

Comment: @saulspatz $N$ is the north pole.

Comment: @Saulspatz I think if we take a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $D^2 \setminus S^1$ converging to a point of $S^1$ then $|x_n| \to 1$ and hence $\frac {x_n} {1 - |x_n|} \to \infty$ (since $|x_n| \lt 1,\ \forall n \geq 1$) and hence any point on $S^1$ corresponds to the point at infinity. That is why $\mathscr {I}$ sends every point on $S^1$ to the north pole which clearly makes $f$ continuous.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I just wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $S^1$, $f$ is constant.  We must show that if $x_n\to x\in S^1$, where $x_n\in D^2$,  then $f(x_n)\to N$.  That seems clear.  As $|x|\to1$, $\left\lvert\frac x{1-|x|}\right\rvert\to\infty$ and $$\mathscr I\left(\frac x{1-|x|}\right)\to N$$

Answer (score 0):

Another proof (less explicit but topologically correct): $D^2\setminus S^1$ is just the open unit disk which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. So when we form $D^2{/}S^1$ we're left with in essence $\Bbb R^2$ unioned with the identified boundary, which is just a point in the quotient space, and together the form a compact Hausdorff space. So $D^2{/}S^1$ is just a one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^2$ and by unicity of that space it's homeomorphic to $S^2$, another one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^2$.